# fakeAsync does not work with debounceTime

Tags: angular, rxjs, jasmine, debouncing

I'm trying to write unit test for function in `Angular` app with `debounceTime` (`rxjs`).  And use `fakeAsync` for asynchronous testing.
And it looks that in test `debounceTime` gets resolved immediately even if I don't set `tick()` or set it with small interval like `tick(500)`.

For example with `delay(1000)` instead of `debounceTime(1000)` `fakeAsync` works fine.

**test**:

```
describe('rr', () => {
    it('should get Date diff correctly in fakeAsync with rxjs scheduler', fakeAsync(() => {
        let result = null;
        of ('hello').pipe(debounceTime(1000)).subscribe(v => { result = v; });
        expect(result).toBeNull(); // But it is 'Hello' - debounceTime resolves immediately
        tick(1000);
        expect(result).toBe('hello');
...
  }));
})
```

**stackblitz**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ohhi9e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.spec.ts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `of` operator completes immediately after its notification. If no additional notification is expected, `debounceTime` does not need to wait and thus notifies the moment the complete notification was emitted.

To achieve your result, try using a long-living observable like a `Subject`.

```
describe('rr', () => {
    it('should get Date diff correctly in fakeAsync with rxjs scheduler', fakeAsync(() => {
        let result = null;
        new BehaviourSubject ('hello').pipe(debounceTime(1000)).subscribe(v => { result = v; });
        expect(result).toBeNull();
        tick(1000);
        expect(result).toBe('hello');
...
  }));
})
```

Source: [debounceTime on GitHub](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/debounceTime.ts)

> _complete() {
>       this.debouncedNext();
>   ...
>     }